# Replacing Regular expression matches in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace `&sp;` in the string below with `Z`.

Input text : `ABCD&sp;EF&p;GHIJ&bsp;KL`

Output text : `ABCDZEFZGHIZKL`

Can anyone tell me how to replace the every instance of `&\D+;` using java regular expression?

I am using /(&\D+;)?/ but it doesn't work.

Comment: Voting to close as no attempt shown and your own description of the problem appears incorrect.

Comment: Probably `&\D+?;`

Comment: Thanks @revo. It works.

Comment: Although it works, it matches entire `&;;`. You may want to use `&[^;\d]*;` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

You also should use the `?` modificator to +:

```
String str = "ABCD&sp;EF&p;GHIJ&bsp;KL";
String regex = "&\\D+?;";
System.out.println (str.replaceAll(regex,"Z"));
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Match the initial `&`, then all characters that are not the tailing `;`, then that tailing `;` like so: `&[^;]+;` If not matching numbers (as suggested by your example with `\D`) is a requirement, add the numbers to the negated character set: `[^;0-9]` To make it replace *all* occurrences, add the global flag `g`. The site [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) is a handy tool to create regexes.

*Edit: Sorry, I initially read your question wrong.*